# What do you call a digital instrument file?

Tags: vst, electronic-music, file

Sorry for the obvious question, but I can't find the answer on google.  When you're trying to add digital instruments to a program like bandlab cakewalk, you use some type of file.  I thought it was called .vtx, but I don't think that's quite right.  What file type am I looking for.  I'm almost positive it has x in the name,but could be wrong.  thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  It's not a file its a plugin.  It's called a VST plugin.